# Nested sticky sidebar with scrollable content

Tags: css, flexbox, overflow, tailwind-css, sidebar

I am trying to build a layout that has the following shape:

[image: Layout]

I am trying to build the layout with tailwind css and flex properties but I can't manage to get the second sidebar right. Either the sidebar scrolls with the content or I cannot scroll the content at all.

My tailwind code roughly looks the following:

```
  <div className="flex"> 
    <div className="h-screen sticky top-0">
        { Sidebar1 code ...}
    </div>

      <div className="min-h-0 w-full">
          <div className="flex gap-x-4 p-5">
              <div className="sticky flex-none w-1/5">
                {sidebar 2 code }
             </div>

        <div className="p-5">{content}</div>
    </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

I tried playing with overflow properties but cannot get what I want. What am I missing ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if you meant that the sidebar1 and 2 should always be sticky but I made almost the exact same screen you provided, I added `overflow-y-scroll` to the content `div` to it won't overflow

check it here : https://play.tailwindcss.com/SzzWQnn5Fi

Comment: Thanks! Initially, I wanted to see if a solution with the second sidebar code inside the "content" div existed (because of the way react components are structured currently) but i'm gonna modify the components and use your solution. Thanks.

Comment: @Valentin I think it's possible if you wrap both inside a `flex` div and specify the width for its children have a look https://play.tailwindcss.com/UkVoWv1NiF

Answer (score 0):

In future, it would be helpful to include solutions that have not yet worked.

If I understand your question correctly, you want to make sidebar2 stay fixed in place while you scroll through content. That can be achieved using `position: absolute`

Positioning with examples is explained [here](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/p/position/)